# Java android google maps api key

Tags: java, android

How can I check my google API-Key, and how I can check how much I have to pay to use Google API-key? 
The log is here: [Google console](https://console.cloud.google.com/), but I do not see where I can check this information

Comment: This community helps with programming questions; it is not intended to discuss the cost or detailed nature of some 3rd party service. So please turn to the [help/on-topic] to learn what to ask here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Tap Navigation icon at the top left then look for APIs & Services then click Credentials.

you can add restrictions to your key by tapping the key name.

[image]

Comment: Ok and I have one more question is this  for free or I have to pay for get last postion ? LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(getGoogleApiClient());

Comment: It's free while debugging. But when you go live on Google play store you have to pay.

Comment: What does mean live on Google play store ?

Comment: If this apk is on store I will pay when I want to get current posstion ?

Comment: So when i have API key and use LocationServices.FusedLocationAp I will pay for this ?

Comment: I can not find any inforamtion about it

Comment: No dear. I am talking about google APIs and services. like Map api.

Comment: What kind of issue you are facing?

Comment: Ok sorry now I asked you for LocationServices.FusedLocationApi ,

Comment: it will work properly. No need to add a payment method.

Comment: So I underd stand and this method is free ?